# Powershell command not being properly called by Ruby

Tags: ruby, powershell

I'm attempting to write a ruby class that parses a date in powershell, however when executing the command via Ruby, I'm getting the following error:

```
'select' is not a recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

Here is how I have it written in Ruby:

```
`powershell (Get-Hotfix | sort installedon | select -ExpandProperty installedon -Last 1).ToShortDateString()`
```

Any thoughts? It works fine when I enter it into powershell myself. I'm wondering if it has something to do with the piping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backtick (`` ` ``) in Ruby is calling a shell command, so forget that you're calling it from Ruby and just put everything that's in your backticks in the command prompt and you'll see the same error. Fix it there first.

The problem is that pipe `|` is a special character in the command prompt, and you have spaces in your command, so you should be quoting the PowerShell command before you pass it to `powershell.exe`:

```
`powershell.exe -Command "(Get-Hotfix | sort installedon | select -ExpandProperty installedon -Last 1).ToShortDateString()"`
```